# Correct way to access Yii2 components in your modules?

Tags: php, yii2

I have created and configured a module fooModule. I need to create a component inside the module.

This is my configuration for my module in main.php

```
'modules'=>array(
    'fooModule'=>array(
         'class' => 'app\modules\fooModule\Module',
         'components'=>array(
            'testComponent'=>array(
                'class'=>'app\modules\fooModule\components\testComponent',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

In the folder module fooModule i have created a folder components with  a file testComponent.php

TestComponet.php has a class test which extend \yii\base\Component. See below

```
namespace app\modules\fooModule\component;

class test extends \yii\base\Component {

        public function __construct() {
                private $bar;     
        }

        public function exampleFunction() {
                echo 'am alive, come and look for me please!!';     
        }

}
```

> How do i access test class in fooModule Controller ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `Yii::$app->getModule('fooModule')->testComponent->exampleFunction();` for access module component.

Comment: Thank for your response let me try it out

Answer (score 3):

The most elegant way to access module component from module controller without hardcoding module's ID is as follows:

```
$this->module->testComponent->exampleFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks very elegant

```
Module::getInstance()->testComponent
```